# How do I apply my function to my list of arguments?

Tags: functions

I have a list of integers

```
l := {3, 5, 7}
```

and a function

```
f1[a_] := a + 1
```

I would like to apply `f1` to each of the elements of `l`. According to [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingFunctionsToListsAndOtherExpressions.html) official Mathematica documentation, `Apply` makes each element of the given list an argument of the given function. However, this does not seem to be the case, as:

```
Apply[f1, l]
```

returns:

```
{3, 5, 7}
```

Idem with the "shorthand" `f1 @@@ l`. What's going on? Why isn't `Apply` doing what the official documentation says it should?

Comment: Take a look at `Map`

Comment: `Apply[f1, l]` does not return `{3,5,7}`. It returns `f1[3, 5, 7]`.  This is precisely what the documentation says it would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the meaning of the documentation wrong. It says it *makes each element and argument*. That is different from *it applies f to each element*.

You can see what it means when each element is made an argument to a function

```
Apply[func, {1, 2, 3}]
(* func[1, 2, 3] *)
```

You want something else

```
Map[func, {1, 2, 3}]
(* {func[1], func[2], func[3]} *)
```

Comment: Footnotedly: Since Apply removes a level of list,  Apply[f, List[l]] would work.